# JS get element return undefine

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I want to change the values of the buttons on the page with Tampermonkey, but I can't change it because it says the button is undefined?

HTML part

```
<div class="playbackRateButtons">
  <span>Playback Speed ： </span>
  <button class="btn blue" value="0.5">0.5X</button>
  <button class="btn blue" value="0.75">0.75X</button>
  <button class="btn blue active" value="1">1X</button>
  <button class="btn blue" value="1.25">1.25X</button>
  <button class="btn blue" value="1.5">1.5X</button>
</div>
```

My Tampermonkey Script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto Change Speed
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://xxxxxx/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @connect      xxxxxx.html
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://xxxxxx.html",
    onload: changeSpeed()
});

function changeSpeed(response) {
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn blue");
    var speed = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "10"];
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        btns[i].value = speed[i];
        btns[i].innerHTML = speed[i]+"X";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the buttons in question on the web page this script runs on? If so, are they part of the HTML source, or are they dynamically added by scripts on the web page?

Comment: They are a part of the HTML source.

Comment: Does the for loop iterate multiple times before creating an error, or does it immediately break on the first item? (What is the specific error message?)

Comment: These are the error messages in the console.
https://imgur.com/J3hxEg2 https://imgur.com/ITc7ohB
And it immediately causes an error on the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your `changeSpeed` function. It tries to select the buttons at 1 second interval (you might want to update this interval). If found `clearInterval` is called and the rest of the code is executed.

```
function changeSpeed(response) {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn blue");
        if (btns.length > 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            var speed = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "10"];
            for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                btns[i].value = speed[i];
                btns[i].innerHTML = speed[i] + "X";
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```